# Jquery slide down menu if else condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a slide down menu using `JQuery`. I thought I'd base it around this logic, that if the menu had the class `activated` then when it is clicked it should be closed. Otherwise it is not open so it should be open.

The code below is a basic version of what I'm trying to achieve, but for some reason it never gets into the `clause`. Every time I click the item the alert box saying "Close" comes up.

```
 $('#openMenu').click(function(){
                        if($('#openMenu'.hasClass('activated'))){
                            alert('close');
                            $(this).removeClass('activated');
                        }else{
                            alert('open');
                            $(this).addClass('activated');
                        }
                    });
```

Can anyone see where I might be going wrong? I should point out that when the page loads the div does not have the class `activated` applied to it.

Comment: First thing I would do is look into the browser console for any errors. Clearly, `$('#openMenu'.hasClass('activated')` has a syntax error.

Comment: It doesn't have any syntax errors, the first thing I did was check the console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#openMenu').toggleClass("activated");
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your syntax for checking the element's class has issues, it should look like this:

```
if($('#openMenu').hasClass('activated')){
```

Here is the working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dnsdrzym/2/